# I can't understand this MediaPlayer error: MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x7efba92280)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

When the app starts everything is fine. But after some time it stops playing sound. but the app does not crash. I didn't understand what wrong with it.

Here my MediaPlayer code:

```
 holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mediaPlayer!=null){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(mContext,mChineseLanguages.get(position).getSound());
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });
```

In logcats the following error is being displayed

```
MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, 
mPlayer(0x7efba92280) MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement mediaPlayer's onPreparedListener and start the player inside it. The abover error is producing because you are starting the player before it reaches the onPrepared state.

**For example-**

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url); 
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: _"The abover error is producing because you are starting the player before it reaches the onPrepared state"_. A `MediaPlayer` created with the `MediaPlayer.create` method will already be in the *Prepared* state when `create` returns. Also, the error message refers to `stop`, not `start`.